# How to build Tensorflow for my AMD Linux system?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, amd-gpu

I recently installed TensorFlow onto my system. Upon fitting to the model, I am getting this error in the Jupyter Notebook terminal:

```
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

I read that I am supposed to build TensorFlow for my system, but I am unaware how to. What kinda settings do I need to set? What compiler flags do I need? Here is my setup:

- GPU: AMD RX 5700XT
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
- RAM: 64GB DDR4
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Can someone give me advice on how to build TensorFlow for my system?

Comment: https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream check this out, maybe will come handy

Answer (score 0):

Most deep learning and machine learning frameworks and libraries use NVIDIA CUDA for GPU processing, we would need to select an NVIDIA graphics card.

Note While Amd has some excellent graphics card models, their compatibility and support with ML tasks are still experimental. So we will need to stick to NViDia.

AMD provides a ROCm enabled TensorFlow library for AMD GPUs. It's based on the ROCm software stack. To know more about this library: MIOpen - ROCm.

Based on these factors, the following graphics cards families can be recommended:
GeForce 10 series
GeForce 16 series.
GeForce 20 series.
GeForce 30 series